# Starting a new page instead of appending under router-outlet

Tags: angular

Not sure if it's a duplicate... but is there a way to start a new page instead of appending/replacing the `<router-outlet>` ?

I was following the Angular tutorial on routing https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 and it seems like I can only append instead of starting a new page....

**Edit**

Sorry I should've made this clear.. I wanted to do something like

`<a href="index.html"> go to index page`

`<a href="page1.html"> go to page 1`

This way, I can have entirely different contents in index.html and page1.html. Whereas in angular, whatever contents I have above `<router-outlet>` will get carried to the next page.

Since Angular is designed for single-page application, is there no way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by starting a new page?

Comment: Angular is designed to make single page applications, so the idea of a new page is somewhat antithetical to that goal.

Comment: Do you mean you want to navigate to a new page outside of the angular app? ie. `window.location.href = url-here`?

Comment: Updated to make my question more clear

Comment: Is this not what happens if you use a plain `a` tag without the `routerLink` directive?

Comment: @IvanS95 just wondering if there's a more angular way (like calling the component instead of html file) to do it other than <a href>